# Sum column values on dataframe on the bottom of columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe with different columns with different values, I would calculate the sum of the values for each column and put the result on the bottom of each column

So i have a dataframe like this:

| TEAM | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RED | 4 | 12 | 3 |
| RED | 2 | 1 | 1 |
|  |  |  |  |
| BLUE | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| BLUE | 2 | 5 | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |
| YELLOW | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| YELLOW | 1 | 2 | 5 |
|  |  |  |  |

And I want this as result:

| TEAM | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RED | 4 | 12 | 3 |
| RED | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| **SUM** | **6** | **13** | **4** |
|  |  |  |  |
| BLUE | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| BLUE | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| **SUM** | **5** | **6** | **6** |
|  |  |  |  |
| YELLOW | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| YELLOW | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| **SUM** | **2** | **4** | **10** |
|  |  |  |  |

IDK how to do that

Thank you

Comment: Share your approach?

Comment: why not use a seperate dataframe for each team (eliminating the team column) and then just use the `sum` method of the dataframe?

Comment: You can use 'groupby` or `iteration` with `.loc`